# Add a confirmation dialog before suspending people on chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, confirmation, chat-ban

At the moment, suspending folks in chat is pretty easy: You press a button, and they can't chat for an hour.

The problem is, this button doesn't have any sort of confirmation. It just... goes ahead and suspends them. This doesn't make sense; the "refresh profile" button, right next to it, *does* have a confirmation dialog, but the suspension doesn't.

This is not normally an issue, but I've accidentally suspended a user while trying to refresh their profile before. Entirely my fault, and I immediately unsuspended them and apologized, but it'd still make more sense for the suspension button to not be so easy to fat finger.

<sub>don't yell at me, Shog</sub>

Comment: [[tag:status-declined]] because reasons.

Comment: You suspended Shog?

Comment: Nah, can't suspend a mod from chat, @rene   ;)

Comment: @Catija - [Well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0vEG.png)... I've done *that* before ;)

Comment: Or just set the default to 0. Its not like there's any guidance on how long to suspend someone? ... though suspending someone for 0 hours is... trippy.